# Select Two Values Based Off Same Column

Tags: mysql, sql, select, pdo

I am trying to select two usernames in one row of a query one would be called 'username' and the second one say 'username2'. This is the code I have atm. The users table uses a primary key of user_id.

```
SELECT
  r.report_id,
  r.poster_id,
  r.reporter_id,
  u.username,
  (2nd username)
FROM reports r,
  users u
WHERE r.report_id = :report_id
    AND r.reporter_id = u.user_id
    AND r.poster_id = u.user_id
```

Comment: I want to return username1=r.reporter_id=u.user_id and username2r.poster_id=u.user_id in the same row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to join the table `user` twice

```
SELECT 
        r.report_id,
        r.poster_id,
        r.reporter_id,
        u.username AS ReporterName,
        b.userName as PosterName
FROM
        reports r
        INNER JOIN users u      
            ON r.reporter_id=u.user_id
        INNER JOIN users b
            ON r.poster_id=b.user_id
WHERE
        r.report_id=:report_id
```

Comment: Just one other thing how could I add an optional clause to that so like say it must find reporter_id in user table but poster_id can be optional whether its found?

Comment: use `LEFT JOIN`. you mean `poster_Id` is optional. Right? `LEFT JOIN users b
            ON r.poster_id=b.user_id`

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code for MySQL

```
        SELECT
          r.report_id,
          r.poster_id,
          r.reporter_id,
          u.username,
          u.username username2,
        FROM reports r,
          users u
        WHERE r.report_id = :report_id
            AND r.reporter_id = u.user_id
            AND r.poster_id = u.user_id
```

Comment: this will give invalid result. since there are two columns requiring the the value from the other table `user` you need to join it twice.